# Are there any issues with using log4net in a multi-threaded environment?

Tags: log4net

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience using log4net in a multi-threaded environment like asp.net.  We are currently using log4net and I want to make sure we won't run into any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run log4net (and log4cxx) in highly multi-threaded environments without issue.  You will want to be careful how you configure them though.

The issue with log4net that Jeff describes pertains to the use of a certain appender.  We stick with simple log file appenders on the whole to reduce the impact of logging on the operation of the code. Writing a line to a file is pretty minimal, kicking off another database transaction is very heavy.

Comment: So the database appender is what was giving Jeff the locking issues that he discussed in the podcast.  Unfortunately we are using the database appender because we wanted a centralized log repository.